# Jackson Polymorphic Deserialization Field Errors

Tags: java, spring, polymorphism, jackson

I am getting error when trying to deserialize json into an abstract type.

**Code:**

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="@class")
public abstract class Animal
{
}

public class Dog extends Animal
{
}

public class Zoo
{
    Animal a;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/zoos", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void create(@RequestBody Zoo zoo)
{
  ...
}
```

When I post the following json to zoos:

```
{
    "@class": "com.example.Dog",
    "a": {}
}
```

I get the error:
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "@class" (Class com.example.Zoo), not marked as ignorable

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I'm an idiot:

The json should be:

```
{   
    "a": {
        "@class": "com.example.Dog"
     }
}
```

because the @class belongs to the type animal.

Comment: FWIW, I think there is a newish config to externalize the type element to the same nesting level in the JSON as the target object.  In other words, it moves the type element outside of the target object.